# Looking to do a simple script for compressing and decompressing a file in linux

Tags: linux, zip, 7zip

I need to take a 7z file and uncompress it, then recompress it with zip, and I'd like to do with this with a script, what's something quick and basic I can use? It's centos if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  refer to [repack-7z-files-to-zip-files-in-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1115548/repack-7z-files-to-zip-files-in-linux):

```
#!/bin/bash

TMPDIR=tempdir_$$

for x in `ls *.7z`; do
    mkdir $TMPDIR
    cd $TMPDIR
    cp ../$x .
    p7zip -d $x
    zip -r ../${x%.7z}.zip *
    cd ..
    rm -rf $TMPDIR    
done
```

Personally I use the `7z` command on Ubuntu (`p7zip-full` package) that supports both both compression formats.

The complexity of your solution may also depend on whether the 7z file contains multiple files, or just a single file/tar-ball.

Comment: There are a lot of files, hundreds of files. We want to put this into a cron job so no one has to babysit the unpacking and repacking of the file.

Comment: @badblue ok, then this is your solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the reply!